# Deriving mean through MGF for discrete uniform distribution

Tags: probability-theory, generating-functions, expected-value

The MGF of a discrete uniform distribution is given as

$$M_X(t) = \frac{e^t(1-(e^t)^k)}{k(1-e^t)}$$

Looking for $E(X)$, I am computing $$M_X'(t) =\frac{(k(e^t-1)-1)e^{(kt+t)}+e^t}{ k(e^t-1)^2}$$

which doesn't make sense cause denominator will become zero and mean should be $$E(X)=\frac{k+1}{2}$$

How do I get the mean from the MGF? I can't seem to find out where I went wrong.

Comment: It very much makes sense because the numerator also goes to zero when $t\to0$. Thus, simply use $E(X)=M_X(0)$ by computing $$M_X(0)=\lim_{t\to0}M_X(t)$$

Comment: This is the first time I'm coming across the formula. Do you know where I could look it up

Comment: Which formula? You invoke yourself the fact that $E(X)=M_X(0)$. The fact that $M_X(0)=\lim\limits_{t\to0}M_X(t)$ is the continuity of $M_X$ at $0$, a most standard property, holding as soon as $E(X)$ is finite, and explained almost [everywhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function).

Comment: I thought $E[X]= M_{X}'(0)$. This is the first time I came across $E[X] = M_{X}(0)$

Comment: OK, obvious typo in my comments, please read $E(X)=M'_X(0)=\lim\limits_{t\to0}M'_X(t)$.

Comment: Got it, thank you. :)